# Related work or related works

Tags: plural-forms

I see both "Related Work" instead of "Related Works" phrases in papers. Assuming either one of these could be used, can someone explain why that is so? If more than one reference is listed, it seems the heading should be "related works" (plural) or maybe the those that say "Related Work" are in error?

Comment: Some people are downvoting/closevoting this question, probably because you've asked the either/or question: "Which one should be used?" (If you've seen them both, there's a good chance **both** could be used, right?) I'm going to edit your question in a way that might make it more about English, and see if I can't stave off the negative feedback. Feel free to do a rollback on the question if you think the new form doesn't address your concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that both *related works* and *related work* are used in papers, and both are correct. Furthermore, according to Google n-grams, *related work* is roughly 4 times more common than *related works*, though it is difficult to know if these occurrences are within the context of papers such as you are interested in.

An explanation for why both are correct comes from the different meanings of *work* and *works*. *Related works* refers to publications themselves, while *related work* refers to the actual work behind the publications.